# SQL XML XQUERY - Looks right, NULL/empty value returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm newish to XML XQuery and such but this sure looks like it ought to work.

XML fragment

```
<Contacts>
  <Contact ContactID="7" FileType="MS">
    <ID>7</ID>
    ....
    <Comments ContactID="7" />
    <CompanyID ContactID="88">Some New Value</CompanyID>
    <CompanyName ContactID="7">Some New Value</CompanyName>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I pass in `@SourceField` to the stored procedure. In this case its value is `CompanyID`. I then create a variable I call `@xmlPath`.

```
SET @XmlPath = '/Contacts/Contact/' + @SourceField
```

I retrieve the XML from the table into a variable named `@ContactData` (see fragment above)

I then create a variable `@SqlCmd` and execute it.

```
SET @SqlCmd = 'SET @ContactID = @ContactData.value(''(' + @xmlPath + '/@ContactID)[1]'', ''nvarchar(max)'')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlCmd, N'@ContactID nvarchar(20), @ContactData XML',@ContactID, @ContactData
```

I issue three SQL commands to test the values.

```
SELECT @ContactData AS ContactData
SELECT @SqlCmd AS SqlCmd
SELECT @ContactID AS ContactID
```

The first returns the XML from the table. (see fragment above)

The second returns the following;

```
SET @ContactID = @ContactData.value('(/Contacts/Contact/CompanyID/@ContactID)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

which looks correct but...

and the third returns `NULL` when I would expect `88`. Also, when I initialize `@ContactID = ''` I receive the empty string.

So, my conclusion is that I am missing an assignment process somewhere but the code looks like every example I've seen online that does work. I MUST be missing something simple.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the parameter `@ContactID` as an output parameter.

Try this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlCmd, N'@ContactID nvarchar(20) out, @ContactData XML',@ContactID out, @ContactData
```

Comment: Hi Mikael,    Thanks! That solved the issue. I just KNEW it had to be something simple. Last night, while trying to go to sleep at midnight after wrestling with this issue I thought it had to be something like this. I VERY MUCH appreciate the second set of eyes! I was, in fact, missing something very simple. :)